# Reverse string translation with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to reverse the use of the `translate` function. I pass a dictionary into `str.maketrans`, which translates the original string correctly, as per the dictionary.

```
cipher_dictionary = {'a': 'h5c', 'b': 'km3', 'c': '5fv'}

def cipher(text):
    trans = str.maketrans(cipher_dictionary)
    return text.translate(trans)
```

Above is the sample dictionary, together with the function that I use to translate strings. Translating `abc` gives me `h5ckm35fv`, which is desired.

Now, to reverse it, I am trying to use the following function.

```
def decipher(text):
    reverse = {value: key for key, value in cipher_dictionary.items()}
    trans = str.maketrans(reverse)
    return text.translate(trans)
```

Using it raises an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\cipher.py", line 21, in <module>
    deciphered = decipher(ciphered)
  File "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\cipher.py", line 13, in decipher
    trans = str.maketrans(reverse)
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
```

I am aware that this is because the values in `cipher_dictionary` aren't equal length to a, b and c. How can I go about rewriting the `decipher` function, to make `h5ckm35fv` translate back into `abc`?

```
cipher_dictionary = {'a': 'h5c', 'b': 'km3', 'c': '5fv'}


def cipher(text):
    trans = str.maketrans(cipher_dictionary)
    return text.translate(trans)


def decipher(text):
    reverse = {value: key for key, value in cipher_dictionary.items()}
    trans = str.maketrans(reverse)
    return text.translate(trans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text_to_cipher = 'abc'
    ciphered = cipher(text_to_cipher)
    print(ciphered)

    deciphered = decipher(ciphered)
    print(deciphered)
```

Running any of the functions provided in answers works perfectly, except for when there is white space in the input.

```
Text to cipher: some white space
Ciphered text: px3h54oa4b83 ky6u1v0t6yq3b83 px3sy9h5c5fvb83
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz\Desktop\Python\Cipher\cip.py", line 45, in <module>
    deciphered = decipher(ciphered)
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz\Desktop\Python\Cipher\cip.py", line 36, in decipher
    decoded_text = ''.join(reverse[text[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(text), 3))
  File "C:\Users\Lukasz\Desktop\Python\Cipher\cip.py", line 36, in <genexpr>
    decoded_text = ''.join(reverse[text[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(text), 3))
KeyError: ' ky'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def decipher(sentence):
    reverse = {value: key for key, value in cipher_dictionary.items()}
    decoded_text = ' '.join(''.join(reverse[word[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)) for word in sentence.split(' '))
    return decoded_text
```

Assuming that every letter is being encoded into a set of 3 letters.

Comment: Yours and other answers all work perfectly. However, when it comes to deciphering sentences, white space raises an error. Is there a way around it?

Comment: can you provide some example

Comment: Edited the main post.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all cipher values are of length 3 (i.e. that all values in `cipher_dictionary` are three characters long), then:

```
def decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_dict):
    decipher_dict = {v:k for k,v in cipher_dict.items()}
    answer = []
    for cipher in (ciphertext[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(ciphertext), 3)):
        answer.append(decipher_dict[cipher])

    return ''.join(answer)
```

On the other hand, if you don't know that all values are of length 3 (or if they are not of constant size), then try this:

```
def decrypt(ciphertext, cipher_dict):
    decipher_dict = {v:k for k,v in cipher_dict.items()}
    answer = []
    start = 0
    for end in range(len(ciphertext)):
        if ciphertext[start:end] not in decipher_dict: continue
        answer.append(decipher_dict[ciphertext[start:end]])
        start = end

return ''.join(answer)
```

The problem with this is that it is a greedy algorithm and incurs all the shortcomings of its naïvité

**UPDATE**:

If you want to do this with sentences (words separated by whitespace):

```
encryptedSentence = '...'
answer = []
for word in sentence.split():
    answer.append(decrypt(word, cipher_dict))

return ' '.join(answer)
```

Comment: Yours and other answers all work perfectly. However, when it comes to deciphering sentences, white space raises an error. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values in the dictionary for a prefix free code, then you can keep trying prefixes of the unprocessed ciphertext until you find a match in the reverse dictionary:

```
def decipher(text, d):
r = {v: k for k,v in d.items()} # Reversed dictionary
plaintext = ''
index = 0
length = 1
while index + length <= len(text):
    try:
        plaintext += r[text[index:index+length]]
        index = index + length
        length = 1
    except:
        length += 1
return plaintext
```

If the values of the dictionary do not form a prefix free code, then the algorithm involves backtracking, and will return one possible plaintext if the cipher is non bijective:

```
def decipher2(text, d):
r = {v: k for k,v in d.items()} # Reversed dictionary
length = 1
while length <= len(text):
    try:
        val = r[text[:length]]
        if length == len(text):
            return val
        else:
            return val + decipher2(text[length:], d)
    except:
        length += 1
raise ValueError('Malformed input.')
```

Comment: Yours and other answers all work perfectly. However, when it comes to deciphering sentences, white space raises an error. Is there a way around it?